# Golf league payout to six finishing positions

Tags: php

I have a golf league of 40 individuals. We all throw money in a pot and pay out the first 6 places based on final score.

If there were no ties the pay out would be simple but often we have, for example, 2 people tied for first place, 3 people tied for second, 1 person alone in third, etc. The variations seem endless.

I've been trying to automate the calculated payouts for each place using PHP but have not been successful. Any suggestions, help, or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated. I noticed that someone else tried to ask a similar question on this site but was not successful in framing the question. I'll try to do a better job.

Here is some data I've been playing around with:

```
$playerNumber=40;
$totalPoints=100;
```

Payouts:

```
$pointsFirst=0.6*$totalPoints;
$pointsSecond=0.2*$totalPoints;
$pointsThird=0.15*$totalPoints;
$pointsFourth=0.03*$totalPoints;
$pointsFifth=0.02*$totalPoints;
$pointsSixth=0.01*$totalPoints;
```

For the example given above and to pay out six places, we would calculate the payouts as follows:
If two people are tied for first place, we add first and second place points and divide by two.
If three people are tied for second place, we add third, fourth and fifth place points and divide by three.
If one person is alone in third, this person would win sixth place points.

I can count the number of players who are in or tied for a certain place.

```
$countFirst=2;
$countSecond=3;
$countThird=1;
$countFourth=2;
$countFifth=1;
$countSixth=2;
```

In this example the player scores would be 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 75, 75, 76, 77, 77.

At first I thought this was an application for nested arrays. Then I thought perhaps using arrays, array slice, etc, may be a way to go. Each time I end up in the woods. I'm not seeing the logic.

I have used conditional statements for paying out three places but to pay out six places with this method puts me deep in the woods.

Example of payout to three places using conditional statements:

```
$pointsFirst=0.5*$totalPoints;
$pointsSecond=0.3*$totalPoints;
$pointsThird=0.2*$totalPoints;          

if($countFirst>2) {  

    $ptsA=round($totalPoints/$countFirst,2);
}
elseif($countFirst==2) {

    $ptsA=round(($pointsFirst+$pointsSecond)/2,2);

    if($countSecond>1) { 

        $ptsB=round($pointsThird/$countSecond,2);                   
    }
    elseif($countSecond==1) {

        $ptsB=round($pointsThird,2);                    
    }
}
elseif($countFirst==1) { 

    $ptsA=round($pointsFirst,2);

    if($countSecond>1) {

        $ptsB=round(($pointsSecond+$pointsThird)/2,2);                  
    }
    elseif($countSecond==1) {

        $ptsB=round($pointsSecond,2);                   

        if($countThird>1) {

            $ptsC=round($pointsThird/$countThird,2);                        
        }
        elseif($countThird==1) {

            $ptsC=round($pointsThird,2);                        
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I have been clear in my request. I'll be glad to clarify anything. If anyone has any ideas on how to efficiently automate a payout calculation to six places I will be eternally grateful. Thank-you! Mike

Per request:

```
$scores=array();
$scores[0]=72;
$scores[1]=72;
$scores[2]=73;
$scores[3]=73;
$scores[4]=73;
$scores[5]=74;
$scores[6]=75;
$scores[7]=75;
$scores[8]=76;
$scores[9]=77;
$scores[10]=77;

$payout=array();
$payout[0]=0.6*$totalPoints;
$payout[1]=0.2*$totalPoints;
$payout[2]=0.15*$totalPoints;
$payout[3]=0.03*$totalPoints;
$payout[4]=0.02*$totalPoints;
$payout[5]=0.01*$totalPoints;

$countScores=array();
$countScores[0]=$countFirst;
$countScores[1]=$countSecond;
$countScores[2]=$countThird;
$countScores[3]=$countFourth;
$countScores[4]=$countFifth;
$countScores[5]=$countSixth;
```

Comment: I think an array would be super useful here.

Comment: Thanks Aarolama. What would the array contain? Scores?

Comment: Added scores and payout arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, there is a problem with your Payouts. If you add them up you get `1.01` not `1`
`0.6 (1st) + 0.2 (2nd ) + 0.15 (3rd) + 0.03 (4th) + 0.02 (5th) + 0.01 (6th) = 1.01`

**Second**, it is easier if you make your `Payouts` and `Counts` into arrays -
change these -

```
$pointsFirst=0.6*$totalPoints;
$pointsSecond=0.2*$totalPoints;
$pointsThird=0.15*$totalPoints;
$pointsFourth=0.03*$totalPoints;
$pointsFifth=0.02*$totalPoints;
$pointsSixth=0.01*$totalPoints;

$countFirst=2;
$countSecond=3;
$countThird=1;
$countFourth=2;
$countFifth=1;
$countSixth=2;
```

to these

```
$payout=array();
$payout[0]=0.6*$totalPoints;
$payout[1]=0.2*$totalPoints;
$payout[2]=0.15*$totalPoints;
$payout[3]=0.03*$totalPoints;
$payout[4]=0.02*$totalPoints;
$payout[5]=0.01*$totalPoints;

$count=array();
$count[0]=2;
$count[1]=3;
$count[2]=1;
$count[3]=2;
$count[4]=1;
$count[5]=2;
```

Here is the start of one way to do it. Although I would eventually change this into a function so that I can use it again with different payouts, and number of places (see phpfiddle examples below)
I see this in 4 steps-

**Step 1**

```
// Add together the payments if there are ties - ie. 2 tied for first $payout[0]+$payout[1], etc
$payout_groups = array();  // start a payout array
$payout_groups_key = 0;   // array key count
$payout_groups_count = 0;  // array counter, use to match the $count array values
for($w=0;$w<count($payout);$w++){  // 
    if(array_key_exists($payout_groups_key,$payout_groups)){
        $payout_groups[$payout_groups_key] += $payout[$w];  // if there are ties, add them together
    }
    else{
        $payout_groups[$payout_groups_key] = $payout[$w];  // else set a new payout level
    }
    $payout_groups_count++;  // increase the counter
    if($payout_groups_count == $count[$payout_groups_key]){   // if we merged all the ties, set a new array key and restart the counter
       $payout_groups_key++; 
       $payout_groups_count = 0;
    }

}
```

**Step 2**

```
// basic counter to get how many placers/winners. This makes it possible to have ties for 6th (last) place
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
while($y < count($payout)){ 
   $y += $count[$x];  // the $count array values until we reach the amount of places/payouts
   $x++;
}
```

**Step 3**

```
// Create array for winnings per placing
$winnings = array();  // start an array
$placings_count = 0;  // 
$placings_counter = 0;
for($z=0;$z<$y;$z++){
    $winnings[$z] = $payout_groups[$placings_count]/$count[$placings_count];

    $placings_counter++;

    if($placings_counter == $count[$placings_count]){
       $placings_count++;
       $placings_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

**Step 4**

```
// Assign winnings to scorecard
$scoreboard = array();
for($t=0;$t<count($winnings);$t++){
$scoreboard[$t]['score'] = $scores[$t]; 
$scoreboard[$t]['payout'] = $winnings[$t];
}
```

You can see this using your defined values at - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a1g-qu0

Using the same code above, I changed the payout amounts, and increased it to 7th places - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uxi-qgt

Comment: Thank-you Sean! That is some impressive code. I will need to study that a while to get my head around the code. I like your idea of turning it into a function as well. We actually do vary the payouts and places paid depending on how many players show up. But I can certainly work with this. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad I can help you. Make sure to make it as the answer if it helps solve your issue.